# Compare two DataTables and select first table records NOT in the second table

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-dataset, system.data.datatable

I have two DataTables that are getting data from two different sources. I would want to have a new DataTable Table3 with ONLY Tables1 rows that do not have matching Table2 rows. My two DataTables have different structures as indicated below. However, they all share the same primary key - CarReg. So, I would like to compare rows using the CarReg column and return all the rows that are in Table1 but NOT in Table2. My returned Table3 DataTable will have same structure as Table1.

```
Table1.Columns.Add("CarReg", typeof(string));
Table1.Columns.Add("Site", typeof(string));
Table1.Columns.Add("Route", typeof(double));
Table1.Columns.Add("Driver", typeof(string));
Table1.Columns.Add("StartingDate", typeof(string));

Table2.Columns.Add("CarReg", typeof(string));
Table2.Columns.Add("SITE DESC", typeof(string));
Table2.Columns.Add("Route DESC", typeof(double));
Table2.Columns.Add("Driver", typeof(string));
Table2.Columns.Add("KILOS", typeof(string));
```

I have tried the below, however, I am getting all records from the first table Table1. I need to get only records that in Table1 but are not in Table2. So, for example if Table1 have 20 records and Tables2 have 15 records, I need to have only the 5 records. Please help.

```
var recordsNotInB = TableA.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>r.Field<string>("CarReg").Except(TableB.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("CarReg")));
```

Comment: So do you want all the records from Table1 that has no matching CarReg in Table2?

Comment: @YawarMurtaza Yes, I want all the records from Table1 that has no matching CarReg in Table2. Thank you in specifying this in a simple English sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Wihtout knowing any more of your code, I would come up with this.

```
var idsFromTableB = TableB.AsEnumerable().Select(tb => tb.Field<string>("CarReg"));
var recordsNotInB = TableA.AsEnumerable().Where(ta => !idsFromTableB.Contains(ta.Field<string>("CarReg")));
```

Comment: I am getting the same number of records as what I was getting with my code, that is, I am getting the all records in my first table TableA. I need only to get records that in TableA but not TableB. Otherwise thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to come right. Because, I was dealing with a string field column, I needed to Trim the values I was getting on both tables for comparison to work.  Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve performance and also specify the comparison method using a hash set.

```
var idsFromTableB = new HashSet<string>(TableB.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(tb => tb.Field<string>("CarReg")), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

var recordsNotInB = TableA.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(ta => !idsFromTableB.Contains(ta.Field<string>("CarReg")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with next code snippet:

```
        var result = new List<DataRow>();
        //convert to list to avoid multiple enumerations
        var table2List = Table2.AsEnumerable().ToList();

        foreach(var row in Table1.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var matchingRow = table2List.FirstOrDefault(x => x["CarReg"] == row["CarReg"]);

            if(matchingRow == null)
            {
                result.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

You should get collection of DataRows from Table1 that are not in Table2 based on CarReg field.

Comment: This is not working for me. This code its actually returning even more records - something like Cartesian product. Just to clarify, both Table1 and Table2 have same primary structure. Therefore, one record in Table1 will only occur once in Table2 if it happens to be there. So, in my case I want all records that are currently in Table1 but the records(because of the primary key "CarReg") are not yet in Table2

Comment: I added changes that should be able to accomplish the task you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is a long winded solution but i have tested it and it works.

I have done it by creating POCO objects for each Table then taken the differnece as its easier to play with public properties than using Table1["CarReg"] which is prone to errors.

May be someone can improve this solution.

Let your tables to be represented by POCO classes like:

```
public class Table1
{
    public string CarReg { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public double Route { get; set; }
    public string Driver { get; set; }
    public string DateString { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    public string CarReg { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public double Route { get; set; }
    public string Driver { get; set; }
    public string Kilos { get; set; }
}
```

Lets populate the data:

```
IEnumerable<Table1> data1 = new List<Table1>()
            {
                new Table1() { CarReg = "123ABC", DateString = "20/02/2018", Driver = "Driver 1", Route = 45.45, Site = "England" },
                new Table1() { CarReg = "456ABC", DateString = "20/03/2018", Driver = "Driver 2", Route = 55.45, Site = "Scotland" },
                new Table1() { CarReg = "789ABC", DateString = "20/04/2018", Driver = "Driver 3", Route = 65.45, Site = "Wales" },
            };

            IEnumerable<Table2> data2 = new List<Table2>() {
                new Table2() { CarReg = "123XYZ", Kilos = "34KG", Driver = "Driver 5", Route = 45.45, Site = "Karachi" },
                new Table2() { CarReg = "456ABC", Kilos = "44KG", Driver = "Driver 2", Route = 55.45, Site = "Scotland" },
                new Table2() { CarReg = "789CCC", Kilos = "54KG", Driver = "Driver 7", Route = 65.45, Site = "Hyderabad" },
            };
```

Create a list of to hold the result data:

```
 List<Table1> oneList = new List<Table1>();
```

Loop through to identify the rows that are not in Table2

```
  bool matchFound = false; // an indicator if match is found in table 2

        foreach (var item in data1)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in data2)
            {
                if (item.CarReg != item2.CarReg)
                {
                    matchFound = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    matchFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!matchFound)
            {
                if (!oneList.Contains(item))
                {
                    oneList.Add(item);
                }
            }

        }
```

Hope this help!